# How to Automate the salesforce login OTP feature using selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, salesforce

How to automate the salesforce login OTP feature using selenium WebDriver ?

Already tried this option - logged in manually and read the cookies and load the cookies while login using selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simplest way to bypass otp/2fa is to add IP address of server where selenium is run to trusted IP range in Salesforce

In Setup menu, click `Security Controls` -> `Network Access`-> enter the IP address ranges of selenium server.