# How do I bypass the login page when I am testing Salesforce Lightning using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am testing Salesforce Lightning pages on Chrome using Selenium Webdriver code that's in a C# NUnit project in Visual Studio 2019. I get the Login page every time I run a test.
[image]

I used to get the Verification page after the login page but after I added the IP address of the Chrome browser to the list of trusted addresses  as recommended here, 
[How to Automate the salesforce login OTP feature using selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55590030/how-to-automate-the-salesforce-login-otp-feature-using-selenium-webdriver)
the verification page is not coming up anymore.

When I test Salesforce using UFT or Selenium IDE, the login page never comes up.

As can be seen in the attached image, I even have the "Remember Me" checkbox checked.

How can I stop the login page from coming up when I am testing Salesforce Lightning using Selenium Webdriver?

Also, how can Selenium recognize Javascript popups on the page like the Allow Notifications popup in the image below?

[image]

Comment: Hi Burak. You can bypass this issue by having the proper cookies into your opening bot browser. What I mean is that you can export your profile from a browser and include it inside the configuration of your selenium-webdriver. Thus, every time you open the platform having the cookies will not ask you again to follow the login process. Check also here from the official website of Selenium: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/driver_idiosyncrasies/driver_specific_capabilities/

Comment: I do not see anything regarding Chrome on that page. Do you know how Selenium can recognize Javascript popups like the one I included at the end of my question?

Comment: Sorry, for not mentioning. Of course, you can for Chrome too. You can insert a profile instance as an option in the ChromeDriver object. I don't think that selenium can click on that because it's not web element but pop-up from an app. Here is the link that I was talking about: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities AND also one more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33218794/enabling-popup-windows-in-chrome-by-selenium

Comment: So, how can Selenium get rid of that Notifications pop-up?

Comment: There is really vital and detailed answer in StackOverflow already, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684175/how-to-click-allow-on-show-notifications-popup-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: A random upvote in one of m my answers would be appreciated hahaha. Kidding. Keep automating :)